# Repeating a string

Tags: java

I am very new to programming and I have to write a method and program for the following; public static String repeat(String str, int n) that returns the string repeated n times. Example ("ho", 3) returns "hohoho" Here is my program so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // **METHOD** //
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String str = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println(repeat (str));//Having trouble with this line
}

    // **TEST PROGRAM**//
public static String repeat(String str, int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return ""//Having trouble with this line
    }

    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return repeat(str+str, n/2);
    }

    else
    {
        return str + repeat(str+str, n/2);
    }
}                
}
```

I made some changes to my code, but it still is not working

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // **METHOD** //
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a string");
    String str = in.nextLine();
    int n = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println(repeat(str,n));
}

    // **TEST PROGRAM**//
public static String repeat(String str, int n)
{
    if (n <= 0)
    {
        return "";
    }

    else if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        return repeat(str+str, n/2);
    }

    else
    {
        return str + repeat(str+str, n/2);
    }
}                
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be recursive?

Comment: Does it have to be recursive?  Or can you just use a simple loop?

Comment: Add a semicolon on the end of `return ""`.

Comment: I suppose it doesn't have to be recursive, just as long as I have the right output

Comment: @Sabyasachi yes, especially if a Java compiler produces them.

Answer (score 3):

You've missed a semi colon on the line you're having trouble with, it should be `return "";` and not `return ""`

Also,  the line `System.out.println(repeat (str));` should have 2 arguments because you're repeat definition is:

`public static String repeat(String str, int n)`

As a further note, an easier function might be

> ```
>     public static String repeat(String str, int n)
>     {
>         if (n == 0) return "";
>
>         String return_str = "";
>         for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
>         {
>             return_str += str;
>         }
>
>         return return_str;
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static String repeat(String toRepeat, int n){
 if(n==0){
     return "";
 }

 return toRepeat+repeat(toRepeat,n-1);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

2 things I noticed quickly: you forgot a semi-column and your call of "repeat" doesn't match the method signature (you forgot n)

Comment: Good catch user<randomobfuscatednumber>

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing correct arguments while you calling the desired method.

Call as  `repeat (str,k)`  `k` - should be an integer